# Understanding じゃから

Tags: dialects, copula, particle-から, reading-comprehension, role-language

Can somebody please help me understand the following sentence:

> なにをするにも、「おそい」ということはないの**じゃから**。

I am having trouble with the part that I've bolded (じゃから).

I think so far that it means "What ever you do, it doesn't mean ???? "slow".

Comment: I am not certain on this, but it could just be a corruption of だから.

Comment: I have wondered if that were the case.  How would you translate it if that were so?

Comment: The copula じゃ is not a 'corruption' of だ.  Both copula forms じゃ and だ are derived from である.

Comment: So, do you think that it's a negative, as in  じゃない　or　じゃありません？

Comment: じゃ in じゃない is a contraction of で+は, while じゃ in じゃから is a copula. For more about じゃ as 老人語 / 役割語(role language), you could refer to these posts: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/11134/9831　・　http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/34196/9831　・　http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12129/9831

Answer (score 5):

のじゃから is the exact same as のだから; in certain dialects, the plain copula is じゃ rather than だ. This is also used in fictional 'role language' to mark a character as elderly or rural.

Comment: Thank you -- so how would you translate the entire sentence?

Comment: @TeresaS-j I'm afraid I'm not too sure myself. At a guess, 'No matter what he does, you could hardly call him slow.'

Comment: I think it's like.. "No matter what you are going to do, it's never 'too late'."... does it make sense?

Comment: Yes! I think that fits with the rest of it. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Related answer: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/39624/16344

The following list is great & comprehensive --  its stated focus is on recent Anime characters (キャラ語尾, kyara-gobi, Character-suffix)

じゃ ==  often used by 老人キャラ (old(er) folks)

> http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E8%AA%9E%E5%B0%BE%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7
>
> じゃ ==  老人キャラがよく使う語尾。
>
> 容姿が若くみえるキャラでも、設定上用いるケースもある。元ネタは中国地方東部の方言。
> 中国地方では、現在でも老若男女でこの語尾を当たり前のように使用している。

- 中国地方 has nothing to do with China.  中国地方 includes Hiroshima, Okayama, etc.